# Hybris Hotfolder Even though value is there in CSV, getting Empty String in Translator

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder

This is my bean in for the fetching IXA171 GO LIVE DATE – INTERNET to determine approvalstatus of a product.

```
<bean class="com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.impexconverter.CsvImpexConverter">
                <property name="csvDelimiter" value="|"/>
                <property name="operation" value="UPDATE"/>
                <property name="itemType" value="Product"/>
                <property name="headerMap">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="code[unique=true]" value="{SKU Number}"/>
                        <entry key="catalogversion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true][cellDecorator=com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.celldecorator.NviProductCatalogCellDecorator]" value="{STORE}:Staged"/>
                        <entry key="approvalstatus(code)[default='APPROVED'][translator=com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.translator.GoLiveDateApprovalStatusCLTranslator]" value="{IXA171 GO LIVE DATE – INTERNET}"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

CSV has value like so(column no. 129:)
[image: CSV]

```
IXA171 GO LIVE DATE – INTERNET
20231010
```

During debug, the value in the translator, comes out to be **empty**. Not sure why.

[image: translator]
In file GoLiveDateApprovalStatusCLTranslator.java, getting empty string in **importValue()** on **goLiveDateString** parameter.

```
@Override
    public ArticleApprovalStatus importValue(String goLiveDateString, final Item item) throws JaloInvalidParameterException
    {
        if (item == null) {
            String message = "Processed item is null in ArticleApprovalStatus";
            throw new JaloInvalidParameterException(message,0);
        }
```

What could've gone wrong?